# Export a specific line in Notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I have a large XHTML file that contains a lot of code, see the below example:

```
<a:CreationDate>0</a:CreationDate>
<a:Creator/>
<a:ModificationDate>0</a:ModificationDate>
<a:Modifier/>
<a:name>stack</a:name>

<a:CreationDate>0</a:CreationDate>
<a:Creator/>
<a:ModificationDate>0</a:ModificationDate>
<a:Modifier/>
<a:name>user</a:name>
```

How can I export or select a specific line? In the example I want to have such result:

```
<a:name>stack</a:name>
<a:name>user</a:name>
```

and the rest of the code should be ignored.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

okay I found my desire result:

> ```
>  ^((?!<a:name>.*</a:name>).)*$
> ```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems it is a kind of xml document if you want to search a line for example

```
<a:CreationDate>0</a:CreationDate>
or
<a:name>user</a:name>
```

you can search by the closing tags like `</a:name>` or `</a:CreationDate>`

or you can use a scripting language like **php** or javascript to select the line.